# How to make two coordinates match each other?

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates

I am trying to take two coordinates and make them match each other so that a button pops up but I keep getting an error. Here's my code so far:

```
var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var driverLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

func payTime() {
        if driverLocation == userLocation {
            payNowButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

I am using Swift 3, Firebase, and Xcode 8.

Comment: All together now: what's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two CLLocationCoordinate2Ds you can check their lat and long against each other.

```
func payTime() {
    if driverLocation?.latitude == userLocation?.latitude && driverLocation?.longitude == userLocation?.longitude {
        // Overlapping
    }
}
```

However this will only work if they are exactly the same locations. Alternatively you can use something like this:

```
func payTime() {
    if let driverLocation = driverLocation, let userLocation = userLocation{
        let driverLoc = CLLocation(latitude: driverLocation.latitude, longitude: driverLocation.longitude)
        let userLoc = CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude)
        if driverLoc.distance(from: userLoc) < 10{
            // Overlapping
        }
    }
}
```

This converts the two points into CLLocation and then checks how far apart they are in meters. You can play around with the threshold to get the desired results.

**Edit 1:**

Here is an extension to make it easier to compare locations easier.

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D{
    func isWithin(meters: Double, of: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool{
        let currentLoc = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
        let comparingLoc = CLLocation(latitude: of.latitude, longitude: of.longitude)
        return currentLoc.distance(from: comparingLoc) < meters
    }
}

func payTime() {
    if let driverLocation = driverLocation, let userLocation = userLocation{
        if driverLocation.isWithin(meters: 10, of: userLocation){
            // Overlapping
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A poor-quality question like this doesn't deserve a high-quality answer like yours. (voted.) The next step would be to propose an extension `isWithin(meters:of:)` on `CLLocationCoordinate2D` or `CLLocation`

Comment: @DuncanC Thats a great idea! I'll edit the question with an extension.

Comment: I would also add extension to make `CLLocationCoordinate2D`  Equatable